# TypeDoc complains "Cannot find module"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, documentation, typedoc

I have a Typsecript based react app. It works fine but I want to add TypeDoc (think JSDoc for Typescript) to the mix. After installing it I run this from the command line (only processing a single file as I test this):

```
typedoc --module commonjs --jsx react --out ../docs/ ./src/components/404/404.tsx
```

and I get an error:

```
Error: /path/to/project/src/components/404/404.tsx(0)
 Cannot find module 'react'.
```

React is, in fact, installed. I have tried running TypeDoc installed globally and locally and it makes no difference (thought maybe the global install was unable to find the correct node_modules). The app compiles from Typescript and runs fine... no complaints about missing modules or type defs... just won't work via TypeDoc.

Any suggestions? It seems that in order to generate documentation in a Typescript based React project, TypeDoc is the only game in town so I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably it helps you:

```
'node ./node_modules/typedoc/bin/typedoc ' +
(path || './src/scripts/') +
'--exclude node_modules ' +
'--ignoreCompilerErrors ' +
'--experimentalDecorators ' +
'--target ES6 ' +
'--jsx react'
```

And I noticed some error in package.json with default theme:

`--    "typedoc-default-themes": "0.4.0",`

`++    "typedoc-default-themes": "0.3.4",`

Comment: Specifically `--ignoreCompilerErrors` was needed. It still complained about not finding stuff but it also still generated the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: This answer and the subsequent comment was exactly what I needed, i.e. all I needed was `--ignoreCompilerErrors`. As you say, the output still complains but the documentation is still generated. Until a better solution can be found, adding `--logger none` silences the complaining but still leaves the helpful rendering progress bar, i.e. `Rendering [===...===] 100%`. Just note that silencing the logger probably also suppresses other possibly meaningful error messages, so use with caution, and maybe run it every once in a while without the silencing.

Comment: I had to run `npm i typedoc` rather than pulling it on the fly with `npx typedoc --exclude...` everytime.